# How to avoid Email clients having the webversion text in preview for HTML Emails

Tags: html, email

When sending out HTML emails, the first line of text is given as a preview. This being "Having trouble viewing this email? Click here to view it in your web browser"

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: What email client are you using?

Comment: The emails are being viewed in Mac Mail and sent through campaign Monitor

Comment: Does it appear when you send plaintext emails? Or just emails with no images? Are you including images in your emails and are they linked to externally?